# How to make checkstyle check only my staged files?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am working on a multi-module gradle project and I am trying to add checkstyle to it. The problem is that because there is a very large code base already we do not want checkstyle to check everything. I am trying to find a way to make checkstyle check only staged files. Until now I don't have any luck with what I've tried.

What I am trying out now is to pass a new sourceSet but I can't understand how they work. My thinking was to finally have something like this:

```
checkstyle {
  toolVersion = '8.39'
  ingoreFailures = false
  ...
  sourceSet = getStagedSources()
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass a new SourceSet.

I am open to every suggestion even without using sourceSets.

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can add checkstyle as pre-commit git hook to apply checkstyle only for staged files.
You can follow the doc for java projects. https://gist.github.com/davetron5000/37350

Following is an example repo for Go lang projects.
https://github.com/envoyproxy/ratelimit/blob/main/.pre-commit-config.yaml